# How to apply bootstrap styles to angular ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using datepicker from angular.ui, and it styled with empty design which you can see in the [site](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). Now I want to have bootstrap styled datepicker and timepicker without using extra libraries or plugins. Is there a short way to apply bootstrap styles to calendar?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "*bootstrap styled datepicker and timepicker*"? Bootstrap doesn't provide any datepicker nor timepicker component.

Comment: That already has styles applied to it, that's why it looks the way it does. AngularUI is based off of bootstrap. You need to change those classes if you want it to look differently

Comment: @IgweKalu  I've attached files how I want it to look like

Comment: Just override the existing styles to taste. @mcpDESIGNS is right in his statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options to modify the default angular-ui-bootstrap style:

1. Edit the default templates and recompile angular-ui-bootstrap. All the templates are located in the [template directory](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template). E.g. datepicker templates are [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template/datepicker).
2. Override the default templates in you code. By default if you use the `-tpls-` distribution version of angular-ui-bootstrap then all the templates are bundled inside `$templateCache`, see [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js#L3802). So you could provide your own datepicker template overriding the default template e.g. `$templateCache.put("template/datepicker/popup.html"`
3. Or as per the docs:

> If, on the other hand default templates are not what you need you
>   could take ui-bootstrap-[version].min.js and provide your own
>   templates, taking the default ones
>   (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template) as a
>   starting point.